# MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [test.users]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I am using MongoDB Atlas as my database and Mongoose for my Node.Js/MongoDB backend. I was able to successfully connect my Express server with MongoDB Atlas. However, when trying to create a Put call to this database, I am prompted with the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [test.users]
```

I have the `readWriteAnyDatabase` role set to my User in Atlas, so I do not believe it has anything to do with permissions configured in Atlas

Comment: After connecting, try running the "connectionStatus" database command to verify that you are logged in and have the permissions you expect.

Comment: What worked for me we to get the collection by doing: db.collection("collectionName")
I then use this object to execute my operations like find, update, and so on. Hope it helps. Let me know if you need a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the "readWrite" role to the user specified in the connection link.

Database Access -> Select User ->Database User Privileges -> Specific Privileges -> readWrite role

Answer (score 2):

In the Atlas cluster, select Database Access tab, press on button Edit on the username then add a role `readWriteAnyDatabase` to the user. Refresh your connection to see the result.