# I can't create a mongodb database. User is not allowed to do action [createCollection]

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, mern

I'm completely new in databases and I'm trying to learn the MERN stack. I successfully created a cluster, but when I'm trying to create a database in MongoDB Atlas, it's just giving me an error:

**user is not allowed to do action [createCollection] on [mydatabase.users]**

What should I do? I literraly can't find the solution for this problem.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81I3T.png)

Comment: This may help you . I have same error this solved mine [ROLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566666/mongoerror-user-is-not-allowed-to-do-action-find-on-test-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In case anyone facing issue during creating an database / collection

Simply do this steps :

- Go to "Database Access" in your atlas tab
- Scroll down to "Database User Privileges"
- Click on "Built - in Roles"
  -Now choose "Admin role"

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to be granted with the [readWrite role](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-user-roles).